# JUnit - getting xml reports?

Tags: android, junit, report

I am following an internet tutorial and it mentions that junit reports should be at /data/data/***/ but my /data/ folder is empty. There is no folder named /data/data. Why is that happening? What is the directory for my reports.

For example I am running this script

```
cd ./App
android update project -p .
cd ../Test
android update test-project -m ../App -p .
cd ../App
ant clean debug
cd ../Test
ant clean emma debug install test
```

It runs tests normal, some of them fail but I can't find my reports with adb after that.

Tutorial is at 
http://blackriver.to/2012/08/android-continuous-integration-with-ant-and-jenkins-part-2-2/

Comment: got the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem to solve you should use a custom test runner.

The author of the article mentioned above forgot to say that he's using this custom test runner: http://zutubi.com/source/projects/android-junit-report/

The instruction for setup is straight forward. I hope this info helps someone.

> - Grab the jar from the [downloads page](http://github.com/jsankey/android-junit-report/downloads) and add it to your libs/ directory.
> - Edit AndroidManifest.xml to set android:name in the  tag to: com.zutubi.android.junitreport.JUnitReportTestRunner.
> - Edit ant.properties to add the line:
>     test.runner=com.zutubi.android.junitreport.JUnitReportTestRunner
> - Run your tests as you would normally:
>     $ ant debug install test
> - Pull the resulting XML report from the device (from the application under test's internal storage directory):
>     $ adb pull /data/data//files/junit-report.xml
> - Integrate the XML with your chosen build tool.

I hope it helps someone with the same problem.
Cheers!